# Windows Authentication for Web Form Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication

What I need to do is allow or deny users access to a specific button control on my asp web form. What I'd like to do is base it off their Windows credentials, so that it is unnecessary to use a login page. Only a few people in the company should have access to this control because it clears a SQL table that holds inventory results and creates a back up.

Is there a way to authenticate when Default.aspx loads and if authenticated, make DeleteButton.Visible = true?

In the meantime, I'm taking a look at ASP windows authentication tutorials. Most of the tutorials seem geared towards allowing or denying access to the web form in general, but other users should be allowed to access the form (just not the delete button).

Comment: are the people who should have access to this button going to be logging in first?

Comment: no i was hoping to not use a login page. instead, authenticate based on windows credentials taken from the PC that's logged into, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
DeleteButton.Visible = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
                       User.IsInRole("AllowedToPressButton");
```

As you have no login logic as such (because Windows has already done the authentication) you'll need to handle which specific users are in the "AllowedToPressButton" group.

To make the above example work try the following:

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

**global.asax**

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (Roles.RoleExists("AllowedToPressButton") = False) Then
        Roles.CreateRole("AllowedToPressButton")
        Roles.AddUserToRole("DOMAIN\User", "AllowedToPressButton")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is a very simple way of implementing the solution and it tightly binds the user/role assignments. Role management in ASP.NET can implemented in several ways such as SQL or Windows (and more).

Here are a couple of good articles about using custom roles and windows auth

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application

Comment: Yes, so that is essentially what i want to do, but the login logic is where the problems arise. The only login that happens is when a user logs into their computer. Is it possible to do this: <allow users="(domain/user)"/> in web.config? Then based on allowed users in web.config, authenticate and make button visible?

Comment: check my edit. I just read Scott Guthrie's article about this and it looks like it might be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to take a look at this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to make the 'login' logic part work.

Comment: No worries, glad to have been some help! If you think it is appropriate can you mark as the answer. Cheers : )